# Any particular ports to use with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, nginx

I'm building a web platform at the moment with NodeJS and Express. I have 3 subdomains linked to the platform each running their own NodeJS app.

```
auth.example.com
api.example.com
example.com
```

I'm busy setting up Nginx and as far as I can tell, I need to create 3 server blocks routing each of the 3 subdomains to the apps running on the localhost on different ports. My question is if there are any particular ports that I should use for each of the apps or if it's completely irrelevant?

For instance it'll have to be set up as follows:

```
example.com:8000
auth.example.com:8001
api.example.com:8002
```

with an example server block of:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name api.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass: http://127.0.0.1:8002;
    }
}
```

Any conventions or recommended ways to set this up? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's completely irrelevant which ports you choose as long as they are above 1024 and nothing else is already using the port.  Your 8000 series is just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no any particular ports for this purposes. But you can use unix socket files if you want additional isolation.

Configuration example for auth socket:

```
...
location / {
    proxy_pass http://unix:/var/app-name/auth.socket:/;
}
...
```

Don't forget to grant write permissions for web server's group.

Comment: Could you show me an example of how to set that up?

Comment: Add configuration example

Answer (score 0):

Anything over 1024 should be fine so long as they're unique to your project